# VB.NET List(Of String) to Long()

Tags: vb.net

how do I convert a List(Of String) to Long() ? 
I have this :

```
    Dim List As New List(Of String)
    List.Add("0044001")
    List.Add("0044002")
    List.Add("0044003")
```

And I need to convert it to Long() because function parameter is "long[] msisdns" (C# library), I can do `New Long() {0044001,0044002,0044003}` but it is not what i want , or how do I add to the Long array ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx):

```
Dim Longs = (From s In List
             Select Convert.ToInt64(s)).ToArray()
```

If you don't want to use LINQ,

```
Dim Longs2 = List.ConvertAll(AddressOf Convert.ToInt64).ToArray
```